# How can I create a desktop Symlink to a Google Drive sub-folder?

Tags: nautilus, symbolic-link, google-drive

I would like to create a symlink on my desktop to a folder within google drive.

I have already added Google Drive as a Nautilus window sidebar bookmark & I found it is also possible to drag sub-folders from google drive to make a sidebar bookmark too.

However, what I am asking is how to place a bookmark or symlink like this on the desktop.

I tried to create a symlink using the following. The path was acquired by dragging the mounted folder into terminal.

`ln -s '/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=tripitaka/qw3ER45T6yu8IO0P' ~/Desktop/Gandhara`

This actually works, but the file names & folder names are all encoded & browsing seems very slow.

I also tried the above but using the remote path from the folder properties, which is similar to the example below, but the resulting symlink is not accessible.

`google-drive://username@gmail.com/qw3ER45T6yu8IO0P`